# How do i find the number of relationships between user and permission in DAC and RBAC

Tags: rbac

This is a part of a homework. I don't want an answer, just a hint.

Assume a system with `N` job positions. For job position `i`, the number of individual users in that position `Ui`, and the number of permissions required for that position is `Pi`

1. For a traditional DAC scheme, how many relationships between users and permissions must be defined?
2. How many such relationships must be defined for a RBAC scheme?

Comment: How far have you gotten to come up with an answer of your own? What reading have you done that might help you get to an answer?

Comment: What @Schroeder said. Unfortunately, any proper answer will probably not be very useful, as the answer to (1) is `O(N*P*U*X)` (where "X" is some likely random value dependent more on organizational structure and culture than anything else); and the answer to (2) is `O(N*U*S*X)` (where X is as above, "S" signifies distinct systems that manage their own roles silos, as is "traditionally" done).

Comment: So optimistically, your homework is designed to point you at the inherent administrative scalability issues, and hopefully ways to mitigate this; less optimistically, your teacher has some fantasy about how these schemes are actually used, and/or a marketing-driven fantasy about how efficient RBAC is.